# Django model with historycal change

Tags: django, django-models, model, onchange, history

How can i show model historical changes and show them and can modify?
for example

```
class MM(models.Model):
        chnge1=model.ForeignKey('self')
        changeText = models.TextField(max_length=200)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Django to manage your models you can always look through the migration files to see what has changed. The migration files are designed to keep track of changes to your models so that Django can apply those changes to the database.

See more here: [Django Migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/)

A typical migration file might look like this:

```
from django.db import migrations, models

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [('migrations', '0001_initial')]

    operations = [
        migrations.DeleteModel('Tribble'),
        migrations.AddField('Author', 'rating', models.IntegerField(default=0)),
    ]
```

You can see the 'Tribble' model was delete and a 'rating' field was added to the 'Author' model.

If you have many migrations for a single app and don't want to go through each migration file to see the changes try "squashing" your migration files into (usually) a single file and you can go through all the changes from there.

Squashing Migrations: [Squashing Migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#squashing-migrations)